# Can clerics use swords?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, weapons, cleric

My DM, who hasn't played newer versions of D&D, was asking if my cleric was allowed to use sharp weapons. I double checked the descriptions and didn't see anything like this written there, but now I am doubting myself.

So, can my wood elf cleric use a sword?

Comment: For more information about the sharp weapon thing, see [Why can’t clerics use sharp weapons?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/15358/4563) Note that it does not apply to 5e (or 4e or 3e).

Comment: Wendy, we don't really do updates like that in the question here; they just add unnecessary noise. Usually if you want to post an "update" on what you've done then you would post it as an answer with details about how it solved the issue, [as long as it is an actual answer to the question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Otherwise it's probably best to just leave it out.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Any character can use any weapon; there are no limitations (except size - a medium creature can't use a storm giant's axe or a pixie's dagger). If they are proficient in that weapon they get their proficiency bonus; if not, they don't.

A wood elf cleric is proficient in longsword, shortsword, shortbow, and longbow (from wood elf) and all simple weapons (from cleric). Further, if they are of the Tempest or War domain they are proficient in all martial weapons as well.

By the way, your DM is *really* old (like me); the sharp weapon thing went out in 3rd edition - that is, last century.

Comment: "Last century" oh God don't word it like that!

Comment: @jaska Last millennium, then?

Comment: *cringe* Might as well remind me that I have kids now, too.

Comment: @jaska And just look at how big they're getting!

Comment: Well my DM decided last session that "my God didn't like me spilling blood using all these pointy weapons" in fact none of the gods did in this realm.  So I am intending to smash everyone's chests and getting blood spurting from the smash wounds. Well providing I can actually damn well roll to hit.

Comment: @WendyG Very sorry to see that. I am in the "last century" vintage that Dale refers to as well regarding non edged weapons for clerics. :( and I find the DM's position to be unfair, particularly given wood elf proficiencies.  I guess you have made the best of the situation ...

Comment: Heh, I just came here looking for this answer because I haven't DM'ed since 2e and now find myself running a 5e campaign for my 3 teenage sons and friends.  I assumed the no pointy things thing was still a thing and they just rolled their eyes at me.

Comment: I always thought this was odd, I remember back in 3rd edition days wanting to play a cleric of one of the gods rogues usually worship, my plan was to multiclass between rogue and cleric, my dm at the time insisted that as a cleric I could only use blunt weapons which I found strange given that a god of rogues surely loves anyone that dual wields knives.

Comment: It really originates from a misunderstanding of some actual medieval stuff. Basically the church outlawed priests participating in combat but they were still allowed to protect themselves, so some priests went out on the battlefield with a "staff of office" which was *totally* a religious instrument not an iron-banded bludgeoning weapon, and they were *totally* only there to provide moral support for their side, and if they *happened* to get threatened by enemies, it was hardly their fault that they regretfully had to defend themselves by bashing some heads. Blades aren't plausibly deniable.