# Do Rogue abilities function in wild-shaped beast forms?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, multi-classing, rogue, wild-shape

If I multiclass with Rogue and Druid, am I able to use my Rogue abilities while wildshaped?

Comment: Parker, I've rewrote to hopefully more clearly express your intent. If this was not successful, please rollback.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what material you've looked at to find the answer and what specifically is confusing you (why do you think rogue abilities can or can't be used in wild shape form?). As it stands this seems like a ["read the book to me"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5270/what-do-we-do-with-read-the-book-to-me-questions) question because it can be answered simply be reading the rules.

Comment: Related answer to "Can a rogue multiclass into druid?": https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116322/33569

Comment: Also, it's not necessarily clear what is meant by "rogue abilities" here; that's a very broad question. I'm guessing you're mainly interested in Sneak Attack, but there might be other rogue class features you're interested in.

Comment: @NickParker could you please specify, what "Rogue abilities" do you mean? The prior versions of the question mentioned Stealth, but Rogues does not have some kind of "special" stealth, aside of, to an extent, Supreme Sneak. Do you mean proficiency?

Comment: What Rogue level does the character have?

Answer (score 8):

**Yes**.

From the [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape) rules on PHB page 67.

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.  However, you can't use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new form also has that sense.

You may use any of the rogue features that follow this rule.

Comment: Good answer. It might be worth mentioning that you won't be able to cast spells if you an Arcane Trickster (or other Rogue class that permits the casting of spells).

Comment: It might also be worth noting that Sneak Attack says "The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon", and most Wild Shape forms probably aren't able to use actual weapons - only the "natural weapons" (claws, bite, etc.) of their new form.

Comment: @V2Blast except the ape which can throw rocks with Sneak Attack

Comment: @david-coffron [Not necessarily](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119926/are-improvised-weapons-used-in-melee-actually-melee-weapons)

Comment: @NautArch apes throwing rocks is part of their [statblock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=ape&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=). "Rock. Ranged Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 25/50 ft., one target. Hit: (1d6 + 3) bludgeoning damage."

Comment: Ooooohhh, nice!

Comment: Fairly sure that RAW, the ape wouldn't get Sneak Attack with a rock. There's a difference between a "ranged weapon attack" and an "attack with a ranged weapon."  (According to the [Sage Advice Compendium, p. 10-11](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf)). But RAF, your DM would probably give it to you.

Comment: I think it worth mentioning that "any features from your class" doesn't mean "all that your class gives". A "class feature" is a specific term in 5e, for Rogue it means things like Expertise, Sneak Attack, Thieves’ Cant, Cunning Action, Evasion, etc.

Answer (score 5):

### Depends

Per the [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape), and as the other answer points out:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. However, you can't use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new form also has that sense.

However there is another rule:

> You can’t cast spells, and your ability to speak or take **any action that requires hands is limited** to the capabilities of your beast form.

So while things like Sneak Attack and Dodge may work, Slight of Hand and trying to use thieves' tools will likely fail.

Per suggestion, it should also be noted that:

> The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

It's up to the DM to decide:

- does the ape rock throw qualify as a "ranged weapon" or not
- can it manipulate tools and cards
- is it capable of being "stealthy"

Comment: Do you mean sneak attack? There is no back stab in 5e.

Comment: @NautArch, good catch.. Fixed in answer.

Comment: As per the comments on the other answer: It might also be worth noting that Sneak Attack says "The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon", and most Wild Shape forms probably aren't able to use actual weapons - only the "natural weapons" (claws, bite, etc.) of their new form. So the new form probably can't make an attack that qualifies for Sneak Attack, unless in a form that's able to wield finesse or ranged weapons.